# How to solve Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Validation\Validation::run() must be of the type array or null, object given?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

I'm facing a problem while working on file validation in Codeigniter 4. Codes are given below.

Codes in the validation file are:

```
public $image = [
    'image_path'    => [
        'label'         => 'Image',
        'rules'         => 'uploaded[image_path]|is_image[image_path]|max_size[image_path, 1024]|mime_in[image_path,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png]'
            ]
    ];
```

And, codes in the controller are:

```
if($image->isValid() && !$image->hasMoved()):
    if(!$this->validation->run($image, "image")):
       $this->session->setFlashdata('image_errors', $this->validation->getErrors() ?? "");
       return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    endif;
endif;
```

But whenever I'm trying to run these code, the following error happened:

```
Argument 1 passed to CodeIgniter\Validation\Validation::run() must be of the type array or null, object given.
```

Please suggest me possible solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: The solution is in the error: `must be of the type array or null, object given.` `$image` is an object and it wants an array

Answer (score 0):

When we need to validate form in the controller we follow this steps:

1. use validate() method instead of using $validation property
   see [Controller Validate Data](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/controllers.html#validating-data)
2. set flashdata within recirect()->with() method
   see [Common functions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html)
3. if condition syntax should be with brackets { }, use if else endif in view files only (optional).
   see [Alternate Syntax](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/alternative_php.html)

It's very important and recommended to read [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html)

```
if ($image->isValid() && ! $image->hasMoved())
{
    if (! $this->validate('image'))
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('image_errors', $this->validator->getErrors())
    }
}
```

if you want to use validation class just do this

```
if ($image->isValid() && ! $image->hasMoved())
{
    $this->validation->setRuleGroup('image');

    if (! $this->validation->withRequest($this->request)->run())
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('image_errors', $this->validation->getErrors())
    }
}
```

I hope it will work fine with your code.